# angular material datepicker output

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I've reviewed the documentation on the Angular material datepicker and it didn't work to change to the output. I used some answers here on stackoverflow but they still only changed the displayed format. As you can see in the picture I am unable to change the datepicker output from Mon Feb 11 to the format in the datepicker's input field 11-02-2019 [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIzxD.png). How do I get it to output the format as shown on the datepicker input line instead of Mon Feb 11 and remove the time value attached.

Here is my component.ts so far:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {DateAdapter,NativeDateAdapter,MAT_DATE_FORMATS,MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from "@angular/material/core";
import * as moment from "moment";
import { DatabaseService } from 'src/app/database.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS = {parse: {dateInput: { month: "short", year: "numeric", day: "numeric" }},
display: {
dateInput: "input",
monthYearLabel: { year: "numeric", month: "short" },
dateA11yLabel: { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric" },
monthYearA11yLabel: { year: "numeric", month: "long" }}};
const dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY";
class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
if (displayFormat === "input") {return moment(date).format(dateFormat);}else {
  return date.toDateString();}}}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],

  providers: [
     { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS },
     { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: AppDateAdapter }
]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
get data(): string {
return this.databaseService.serviceData;
}
set data(value: string) { 
this.databaseService.serviceData = (value);  } 

@Input() placeholder;
@Output() onFilter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
@Input() selectedValue;
@Output() selectedValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

private _selectedValue;

constructor(public databaseService: DatabaseService){}

ngOnInit() {
this._selectedValue = this.data;}

onChange($event) {
this.selectedValue = this.updateDate($event.value);
this.onFilter.emit(this.data);}

updateDate(date) {
let formatedDate;
if (date !== undefined) {
  formatedDate = moment(date).format(dateFormat);
}
this.selectedValueChange.emit(formatedDate);
return formatedDate;
   }

}
```

And my html:

```
<div style="top: 50%; position: absolute;">
  <mat-form-field class="datepicker">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]= data>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>  
 <h2 >Data from A: {{ data }} </h2> 
 <input [(ngModel)] = data/>
 <a [routerLink]="['/**']">Go to B</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output object provided from the Material DatePicker already carry all the informations that you need, you only need to print them out correctly.

Try:

```
    <h2 >Data from A: {{data.format("DD-MM-YYYY")}} </h2>
```

Instead of your:

```
    <h2 >Data from A: {{ data }} </h2>
```

Just to be sure, i've tested this on a working project and it work properly.

Edit:

If you need to execute some procedure when the date is changed you need to set up a "listener" [(dateChange)](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#input-and-change-events) on datePicker input, in this way:

```
   ...
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]= data (dateChange)="yourFunctionName($event.value)">
   ...
```

$event.value have the save value of "data" so, at this point, you can remove the [(ngModel)]= data (that is deprecated in [Angular 6](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#use-with-ngmodel))

Then once the listener is set you can create the function in your typescript file that handle the date change.

```
yourFunctionName(event: any) {
    const data = event;
    const formattedDate = data.getDate() + '-' + (data.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + data.getFullYear();
    ... do your operations with formattedDate ...
}
```

Now you have your date correctly formatted available in "formattedDate" variable.
If you need to access this data in your component outside this function you can declare an external variable (like "data" you already create) and reference it inside the function with this.data syntax

```
data: string;

yourFunctionName(event: any) {
        ...
        this.data = data.getDate() + '-' + (data.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + data.getFullYear();
        ...
    }
```

You can indifferently format your date using ".getDate()" & friends or using Moment.

Comment: thanks for the help. I believe it worked for you but when I tried replacing `{{data}}` with `{{data.format("DD-MM-YYYY")}}` and it broke the calendar and the h2 tag showed up with `Data from A:` but it's value is blank.The input field is still saving to the database service to pass data to other components but now no calendar + no output change. I feel like it should just be as easy as adding a .format('format structure')

Comment: Try with the classic syntax for javascript Date:  
`{{data.getDate() + "-" + (data.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + data.getFullYear()}}`  
If this doesn't work, can you tell me which type is the "data" variable, so i can understand which function ara available for extract the information you need.

Comment: Thanks again Simo. That worked but do you know how I can store it in that format in a variable in my service. I want to pass it in that format to use to reference in my firebase database to grab data using that particular string format. So when a user clicks on the calendar it would store the date, ex, 2-2-19 and pass it to the next component where it the var is inserted into , ex db.list('documents/2-2-19')

Comment: "data" variable already store the date info, being bound with ngModel, every time you chose a different date, "data" variable is refreshed, you only need to correctly format the output.
But, if i have understood correctly your last comment, you need to store this result when the date is changed so you need a event that tell you that the user have set a new date right?

Comment: In that case you can use (dateChange) in your input for trigger a function when the values in the datepicker are modified, if you need extra info about let me know that i will update my answer, explain implementation of dateChange is a little unhandy in a comment.

Comment: I would appreciate if you modify it to reflect that, if you don't mind. The variable is storing. I got that to work with the service. When I pick a date then it stores in the service and it carries over to the next component and shows the date picked from the last component but just not in the right format. Even when I call the variable of the date picked it shows it not in the 2-2-19 format but as the "Mon Feb 2 12:59:00 GMT (Eastern Standard Time)" format. So, yeah I'm trying to properly format the output now and implement the dateChange. The output is the trickiest part for me right now.

Comment: So, I do have the `formatedDate = moment(date).format(dateFormat);` in my `updateDate(date) {}` method/function in the component and that returns the `formatedDate` that is already in the right format but how do I now store that? I'm trying to store it into a variable so it can be used. `updateDate(date) {
    let formatedDate;
    if (date !== undefined) {
      formatedDate = moment(date).format(dateFormat);
    }
    this.selectedValueChange.emit(formatedDate);
    this.formatedData = formatedDate; //this 
    return formatedDate;
  }` but the `formatedData` var isn't working.

Comment: Ok. As an update. I got it to store the output as desired. I used `set data(date) { 
    this.databaseService.serviceData= (moment(date).format(dateFormat)); 
  }`. So, when a date is selected the output is stored using the desired format and I can now pass it to the other component when I click the date on the popup material date calendar once. But now the selected date doesn't show in the input field to indicate it was selected until I click the same date again on the calendar.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what do you mean with your last sentence, the method i've showed you is intended only for modify the output date in the format you requested.  

If you need a two way binding in which you provide a date and it's printed and updated from the datepicker the procedure is little different.   

Let me know what you need to achieve and i will update my answer properly

Comment: Yes. I would appreciate if you could update it to show a two way binding, please.

Comment: With your current structure (keeping the ngModel) your problem is that once saved, your date value is a string type and it isn't recognized from the date picker as valid date format, so, for solve your problem you can cast the retrieved data in a correct Date format, and  `get data(): string {return this.databaseService.serviceData;} ` must become `get data(): string {return new Date(this.databaseService.serviceData);} ` up to you set up correctly the rest of your code, then you should update your question to align that to the new scope of the answer.

Comment: I tried `get data(): string {return new Date(this.databaseService.serviceData);}` but it gave me a error: `Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Because you are defining data as string, you should keep it as "any" or "date" type, thats obvious.
What i'm trying to suggest you is, keep the date in "date" format, convert the date in string only when you need to store it, and then if you need to use the date again cast it in date format.
If you pass the date as string in the format you want into the datepicker, it is unable to recognize it as a valid date, and that's why the datepicker breaks when you save the date in your format inside inside data variable.

Comment: Then as last thing, i'm happy to help, but the question is going out of scope, your request was how to properly format the output and your response has been already given, if you want extra detail about your problem i suggest you to adapt your question to your new needs and receive an appropriate answer

Comment: I agree. It might be best to open a new question for the other issue if I am unable to resolve it. But I will try to troubleshoot and figure it out.